# Incredibly tricky situation: 0 bytes space, but I cannot conventionally solve it: Windows is in the way

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, microsoft

I already had this unresolved low disk space problem, but I only let it get worse by not taking appropriate action in time. Now my classes have started and I've gotten desperate to get my laptop running again. 0 Bytes disk space means that I cannot even open Gparted. 
Additionally, I run Windows at the same time, the worst version which does not shut down when you ask it to shut down, it hibernates instead (Windows has this habit of screwing people over while trying to do good). I have forgotten my Windows password, so I can no longer log in and shut down the proper way, **essentially leaving me trapped and barred from using a huge portion of my hard drive space.**

I am trying to consider all my options before proceeding. I do have a USB disk and tried to recover the Windows pass, but nothing worked. I then tried to reinstall Windows, which did not work either. Now, I feel as though my only option is to either increase the partition size (if it is still possible), or try to install Windows from Ubuntu. Is it possible to install Windows in a setup.exe style through Ubuntu?

I am hoping you guys can tell me what the most reasonable course of action to take would be, to just get a functioning device with adequate space to pull me through the semester again (Whether Windows or Ubuntu)

Comment: Do a clean install of Ubuntu, wiping out your Windows partitions.  Then restore your data from your Ubuntu backup.

Comment: Thank you! I can consider this. Is it possible to do a backup with 0 bytes remaining?

Comment: You might be able to image your Ubuntu partitions using Clonezilla, but you probably won't be able to run a conventional backup.  I was hoping you already had a backup.

Comment: Am I likely to run into drivers issues? I don't know what I'd do if my touchpad didn't work after that install

Comment: Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? If so, show me a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` /dev/sda.

Answer (score 1):

I can sketch out a possible solution for you, but you will have to do research to fill in the details of the steps.

1) Create image backups of your Ubuntu partitions (/home if it's separate, otherwise the system partition) using Clonezilla or equivalent.

2) Do a clean install of Ubuntu wiping out Windows.  Make sure the partitions you intend to restore are as big (preferably bigger) than they were before or the Clonezilla restore won't work.

3) Restore the partitions you backed up with Clonezilla.

There may be landmines in this that I haven't considered, I have not done this exact procedure, although I have cloned a Ubuntu install using Clonezilla successfully.